# how to send a different photo with each share to facebook

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, share, meta-tags

Is there any parameter in the facebook share url that I can add an image url to?

I developed a project where the user registers, takes a photo and in the end can share this photo on facebook.

I thought about solving it by changing the meta tag to js, ​​but I'm trying to find a simpler way.

Does anyone have any ideas?

Comment: Changing the meta tags in JS will not do anything. You need to have the user share a unique URL that has the meta tag for that specific image.

Comment: _"Is there any parameter in the facebook share url that I can add an image url to?"_ - no. _Used_ to be, a long time ago - but that has since been removed. Let to too much "fake news", people sharing articles with misleading thumbnail/title/description, that had little to do with what the article was actually about.